# Adjust row height xtable R

Tags: r, xtable

There are couple of helpful posts round dealing with xtable but no one deals with this as far as my search abilities go.

I would like to adjust row height in xtable (print). I'm printing a data.frame.

```
print(xtable(...),...)
```

Please note that I'm already using `add.to.row`

```
addtorow <- list()
addtorow$pos <- list()
addtorow$pos[[1]] <- c(0)
addtorow$command <- c(paste("\\hline \n","\\hline \n",sep=""))
```

So what I would like to do is to widen the `upper` row space:

[image]

I have tried all kind of things but always just messing around what I have already nicely done.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a strut of the appropriate height. That would expand the height, but not print anything. I'm not exactly sure how to do this so I'm only leaving it as a comment, not a full answer.

Comment: Adding extra vertical space is usually done by adding [_x_pt] after \\, and that should be possible to achieve using the `add.to.row` argument of `print.xtable()`. If you show your full `print()` command (and preferably a MWE) you may get a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use the booktabs option which increases the padding around the horizontal lines

```
print(xtable(...),booktabs = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly the context here- if you're using LaTeX or if you're printing the table in html (using R Markdown and rendering as a webpage.  In the latter case you can specify padding on the table cells using CSS rules at the top of your document between style tags:

```
<style>
  th,td{
     padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
  }
</style>
```